# How to serialize and deserialize dictionary values

Tags: c#, .net

How could I serialize and deserialize dictionary values(only values) to and from XML?
I am working on a program with lots of dictionaries and it's not possible for me to change all of those existing dictionaries to  a new "SerializableDictionary" so i was thinking about making my own XmlSerializer or something like that.

I'd like to get a clean Xml like this:

```
<Runnable>
    <MyData>
        <Foo><Name>John</Name></Foo>
        <Foo2><Name>Joe</Name></Foo2>
    </MyData>
</Runnable>

class CustomXmlSerializer{
    public void Serialize(...){}
    public object Deserialize(...){}
}
class Foo{
    public int Name{get;set;}
}
class Foo2:Foo{
    public int Name{get;set;}
}
class Runnable{
    private Dictionary MyData = new Dictionary<int,Foo>;
    public Runnable(){   
    public void Save(){
        CustomXmlSerializer worker = new CustomXmlSerializer();
        worker.Serialize(MyData,"Data.xml");
    }
    public void Load(){
        CustomXmlSerializer worker = new CustomXmlSerializer();
        MyData = worker.Deserialize("Data.xml")
    }
}
```

Comment: ...and your question is?

Comment: And how is the Deserializer supposed to chose the Keys for the dictionary? Your data design and your desired output just don't match.